# Migration of the “Microsoft Graph” Nuget package from V4.5 to V5

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, nuget-package

For a C# project, I use the “Microsoft Graph” Nuget package. Although my project worked fine with version 4.5 of this package, migrating to version 5 causes many compilation errors And the help on the Internet does not provide any detailed solutions.

Example of lines that compiled and no longer compile:

```
await GraphClient.Me.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Content.Request().GetAsync()
```

> Error CS1061 'DriveRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'DriveRequestBuilder' was found (a using directive or assembly reference is is it missing?)

```
await GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[item_id].CreateLink(type, scope).Request().PostAsync()
```

> 'DriveRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' was found that accepts a first argument of type 'DriveRequestBuilder' (is a using directive or assembly reference missing?)

By consulting the Internet:

- I read that “Me.Drive” should be replaced by: Drives[userDriveId].
  By doing the sequence:

```
var driveItem = await client.Me.Drive.GetAsync();
// For example :
var children = await client.Drives[driveItem.Id].Root.Children.GetAsync();
```

- I also read that “Special.AppRoot” was replaced: Special["approot"]
- Finally, the “Microsoft Graph .NET SDK v5 changelog and upgrade guide” says that you must replace “Request().GetAsync()” with “GetAsync()”

Following these recommendations, if I replace my line which has an error with:

```
await GraphClient.Drives[driveItem.Id].Special["approot"].ItemWithPath(filepath).Content.GetAsync()
```

I get the error:

> CS1929: 'DriveItemItemRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ItemWithPath' and the best extension method overload 'DriveItemRequestBuilderExtensions.ItemWithPath(RootRequestBuilder, string)' requires a receiver of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Root.RootRequestBuilder'

I am trying to migrate my code which used version V4.5 of “Microsoft Graph” to version V5 of this package but my attempts are not working.

Comment: Hope the upgrade [guidance](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md) could help you.

Comment: I already know the "Microsoft Graph .NET SDK v5 changelog and upgrade guide". But unfortunately, he is too succinct to answer my question. I think a much more exhaustive list of before/after examples should have been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following page https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2035 gives the solution to the problem.

The functional code is therefore:

```
Drive driveItem = await GraphClient.Me.Drive.GetAsync();
DriveItem appRootFolder = await GraphClient.Drives[driveItem.Id].Special["AppRoot"].GetAsync();
Stream downloaded_file = await GraphClient.Drives[driveItem.Id].Items[appRootFolder.Id].ItemWithPath(filepath).Content.GetAsync();
```